# Elegant/Best solution to get the last element from an iteration

Tags: for-loop, rust, scope

I'm receiving multiple messages over a channel, and after iterating over them, I would like to keep the last element for further usage. My first (probably bad!) approach was to declare some variable, and then assign it every loop.

```
let last = 0;
for some in rx_from_channel.iter() {
   let last = some;
}

let a = last + 5;
```

I really don't like this solution - is there a to avoid assigning `last` in each loop?
Further, I would have expected that after using `let last` inside the `for {}` loop for the first time, the variable declared above the loop goes out of scope - and `ļast` shouldn't be available after the `for {}` loop at all. The compiler suggests otherwise - why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just do:

```rust
let last = rx_from_channel.iter().last().unwrap_or_else(|| &0);
let a = last + 5;
```

See [`last()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.last)

> `fn last(self) -> Option<Self::Item>`
> Consumes the iterator, returning the last element.

Answer (score 2):

Doesn't method [last()](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.last) solve your problem?